# python for-loop getting increasingly slower when the data is a little big

Tags: python

I want to make a comparison between each other in a data set. The data set is a list ,has 20000 members, then my code is just as follows:

```
>>index = 0
>>for i in all:
      index += 1
      begin_time = time.time()
      for j in all[index:]:
           ...
           here are some data processing,then make comparison,
           ...
           print time.time()-begin_time
```

then it get slower with the time, it will take 0.1s every loop at beginning ,and after half an hour, it wil take about 1s every loop.
someone said that it is due to the garbage collection, but when i add gc.disable() before the operation ,it still does not get better.
Who can tell me what should I do?

Comment: `gc.disable()` would just make it worse! Have you tried `gc.enable()` ;).

Comment: just a small tip; you can use `for index, i in enumerate(all):` to get the index and the item

Comment: We sort of need to see the data processing part.

Comment: Comparing each element of an array with all previous elements takes at least O(N^2) time. The inner loop gradually getting slower is pretty much inevitable.

Comment: @Kevin in theory (and just in theory) the inner loop timing should be constant. it prints each iteration

Comment: for me the problem here is memory. slicing create new instances.. so eating memory for about 20k*20k-20k 'items'.

Comment: @Kevin: comparing with all the _previous_ elements? `all[index:]` actually produces a list of all _subsequent_ elements so it should be getting _faster_ instead!

Comment: @PaoloCasciello  :"for me the problem here is memory. slicing create new instances.. so eating memory for about 20k*20k-20k 'items'. – Paolo Casciello 1 hour ago", I think the slice will be transient and will not be live in memory for a long time , is't it? So it is not the reason?

Comment: @tengtengge depends on what you're doing with data. if i try a simple `for index, k in enumerate(l): for index2, k2 in enumerate(l[index:]):
 pass` it's super-fast with no memory overhead.

Comment: @Veedrac  in data processing part ,Levenshtein distance will be caculated between two data and if the two data was similar then logging them to a file.  During this process, some local variables will be used ,but I think in the loop  the local variables will be cover  in each iteration,  it will not reduce the speed, isn't it?

Comment: @tengtengge Are you sure it's not file IO that's getting slower?

Comment: @PaoloCasciello  I calculate Levenshtein distance between the data sets, and some local variables will be used ,but I think  the local variables will be cover in each iteration, it will not eat more memory and it will not reduce the speed, isn't it?

Comment: @Veedrac   Not IO cause, it will not write too much

Comment: @tengtengge try to profile the execution, keep an `iostat -x 2` running or `top`. Check the processor state, if it's iowait and memory usage is not increasing then it's an I/O bottleneck as Veedrac suggested

Comment: @PaoloCasciello Thanks，I have confirmed that it is not I/O bottleneck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is `O(n^2)`, which is pretty bad.
If possible, consider changing the algorithm.

Also, consider using `itertools` instead of manual combination handling.
It will be significantly more readable, and it will likely be more efficent than your approach:

```
import itertools
for i,j in itertools.product(all, all):
  print i,j
```

Comment: actually ,my algorithm is very slow, but I really cann't find out a better way. Because I need to find out all the similar data in the data sets , and these data cannot be sorted to reduce the compare times.   But why it become slower with the time?  It should become faster From the code perspective, for that the first data need compare N times, and the second data only need compare N-1 times

Comment: I see. Although seeing how you are doing data analysis, perhaps a specialized library like pandas would be more efficient. I agree with you that your approach shouldn't get slower. But do try itertools.product and let us know.

Comment: ok, I will have a try.  these is a comment that :"for me the problem here is memory. slicing create new instances.. so eating memory for about 20k*20k-20k 'items'. –  Paolo Casciello 1 hour ago",  I think the slice will be transient and will not be live in memory for a long time , is't it? So it is not the reason?

Comment: I agree with you that it shouldn't live in memory for long. Regardless, you should use itertools instead of manually indexing items.

Comment: I have found the reason, I made some simple mistakes in the function. It is not about any guess they suppose,but I think  your advice is a good one,thank you